# Is it possible to access a java variable from different classes but not be visible to different threads?

Tags: java, java-threads

As I understood static variables are visible/accessible among all threads in JAVA.

Is there a way to define a variable which is only accesible by classes within its thread?

Comment: *static variables* are no good solution in general and your underlying problem may be solved more easily by simply using *local variables* or *object members*.

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with being visible or accessible (not the same thing) "among all threads".

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understand you intention, then yes, it is possible via `ThreadLocal`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private
>   static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
>   (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

Comment: To be clear: the *variable* is visible to all threads, but each thread reads a (maybe) different value.

Comment: The question: *Is there a way to define a variable which is only accesible by classes within its thread?*, answer: *This class provides thread-local variables.*

Comment: I belive ThreadLocal is your best bet and @AndyTurner is pointing you to the right direction. The documentation says "These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID). "

Comment: That itself is the requirement variable visible to all classes within a single thread. I believe Any has a typo "he variable is visible to all threads, ", else bassed on what you mentioned in your query, ThreadLocal is your answer

Comment: @akshayapandey, yes, it is

Comment: @Andremoniy the same variable is visible to multiple threads; `ThreadLocal` is in no way special. However, the value returned by `get()` is different on each thread. That's not a variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner To be precise, the class variable, declared as `ThreadLocal<...> foo` is visible to all threads. But the quasi-variable, which is represented by this construction is essentially visible by one current thread only.

Comment: I think that we are arguing about obvious and everybody known things ;-)

Comment: @Andremoniy There's a slight semantic difference. The visibility of a variable is only determined by its modifiers. As a consequence, so is the visibility of the `ThreadLocal` object it points to. Every thread sees **the same `ThreadLocal` instance**. It's only the object wrapped in the `ThreadLocal` instance that depends on which thread is calling `get()`.

Comment: Am I talking about different things? Where?

Comment: I'm not arguing, `ThreadLocal` is absolutely the right solution, I'm merely clarifying.

Comment: *`ThreadLocal` is absolutely the right solution,* This is the solution for what the OP asked, but you should give her a hint that `static variables` are no good solution in general and her underlying problem may be solved more easily by simply using *local variables* or *object members*.

Comment: Thnx guys, I guess that s what  I was looking for !

Comment: @panipsilos you may find a good tutorial on `ThreadLocalVariables` on [http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends upon whether you mean "to define a variable", or "to define a *value*".

If you mean the latter, `ThreadLocal`, as suggested by @Andremoniy, is the right answer.

If you mean the former, no, you can't do this with a static variable. You can do it by defining member variables on classes, and making sure that instances of those classes are only accessible to particular threads. Trivially:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  Object value;

  @Override public void run() {
    // Do something with value.
  }
}
```

Now, that *variable* `value` is only accessible to its containing instance of `MyThread`. It is only accessible to other instances of `MyThread` if you share the reference to the `MyThread` with other threads. For example:

```
 // In MyThread:
 void swapValues(MyThread other) {
   Object v = other.value;
   other.value = this.value;
   this.value = v;
 }
```